# Using forceUTF8 with email body containing an emoji from a Gmail email converts emoji to "?" and What type of Emoji is a Gmail Emoji?

Tags: php, utf-8, emoji, email-parsing

I am sorry for the title but I had a hard time describing my thoughts. So here we go

I currently have a script that parses emails (not necessarily just from Gmail) in which I get the body of the email and do stuff with it. Works great using this [mail parser](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser)

I started noticing that sometimes the script would break when certain emails came in. I finally realized that it was when there was an emoji in the body, **but it didn't always break everytime**. I would get other emails just fine that contained emojis as well.

With more testing (so far) I now know that it breaks when I get emails with emojis in the body from Gmail emails.

**What's the difference?**

So what I have learned is that Gmail based emojis come in very strange (well for me it is). They are not an image, they are not HEX...nothing that I can tell. They are just a picture (like text) that's not an image. Let me show you a few examples.

**Yahoo (comes in as an image)**

[image]

**Gmail** (comes in as ???)

[image]

Even viewing it right from my database I see the picutre. I can highlight it like text, I can delete it like text, but it's not an image.

[image]

**Now MySQL**

I learned the reason my script was breaking was because I had to have my database set to `utf8mb4` from the connection all the way to the table. I made the changes and it now does not break the script and it stores the emoji fine.

**Now forceUTF8**

I have been using [forceUTF8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) to clean up the body because I am dealing with different characters like other languages.

The problem I am having now is that when I try to cleanup with `Encoding::fixUTF8($body);` it will turn the Gmail based emoji as `?`

**Final Questions:**

My main question is:

Why is the emoji being converted to a `?` when I try to clean it up

My more important question is:

What am I dealing with when it comes to that type of emoji that's not an image or Hex and acts more like text? I feel if I better understood what I was dealing with I might be able to figure out my issue.

Comment:  is a perfectly valid Unicode character. Gmail simply uses those. The library you're using probably has a bug, [it has for other characters too](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8/issues/81). Using `toUTF8` instead appears to work but I'm not entirely sure what the library exactly does.

Comment: "Emoji" is just a subset of "character", likewise you're able to select it just as any other character. Pictures aren't Emojis, and `;-)` are 3 characters. If I tell you that fonts can render characters in multiple colors would you then better understand that an Emoji is nothing more than a character? [Wikipedia: Emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji)